# Allow a URL with a hash to open a tab, but prevent scrolling to it?

Tags: jquery, url, hash

I have a jQuery tabbed element where each tab adds a hash to the URL, like this:

```
www.mysite.com/services#one
www.mysite.com/services#two
www.mysite.com/services#three
```

I want to prevent the default browser behaviour of scrolling to that element (the tab), which I can do with preventDefault.

But I also want to maintain the ability to link to the page with a specific tab already open. So if I visit www.mysite.com/services#three, it should take me to that page with the third tab open, but it should not scroll to that position in the page.

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly possible, but you can open the tab once the page is loaded based on the fragment:

```
//bind click events above

//assumes that ID of tab is the same as the fragment
$(window.location.hash).click();

//scroll to the top, if you really want/need to:
$(window).scrollTop(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this could be.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.scrollTo('0px');
});
```

[Source](http://www.inmotiondesign.nl/playground/?p=20)

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. Adding that code to the end of my jQuery scripts file - or even to the end of the HTML page - has no effect.